# Mysql join get max date related table entries

Tags: mysql

Get the results from follow table max(date)

leads  table

```
id   name   
1    name1  
2    name2 
3    name3
```

follow

```
id lead_id   msg      date
1     1      msg1    20-01-2015
2     1      msg2    22-01-2015
3     1      msg3    24-01-2015
4     2      msg22   21-01-2015
5     3      msg31   22-01-2015
6     3      msg32   24-01-2015
```

What I'm really expecting to see is data like

```
lead_id  name   msg      date
   1     name1  msg3    24-01-2015
   2     name2  msg22   21-01-2015
   3     name3  msg32   24-01-2015

$todayStart = mktime(0, 0, 0, $mon, $day-1, $year);

SELECT * FROM (`follow`) LEFT JOIN `leads` ON `leads`.`id` = `lead_id` WHERE  `date` <= $todayStart GROUP BY `leads`.`id` ORDER BY `follow`.`date` DESC
```

currently im doing join both table tables and using foreach finding max date

```
foreach($resultarray as $p){
SELECT `id` FROM (`follow`) WHERE `lead_id` = ".$p->id." AND `date` > ".$p->date." ORDER BY `updated_on` DESC"
}
```

any help to optimize this in single query

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

```
SELECT
  lead_id,
  NAME,
  msg,
  a.date
FROM lead
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            lead_id,
            max(date) AS date
        FROM follow
        GROUP BY lead_id
    ) a 
    ON lead.id = a.lead_id
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            lead_id,
            date,
            msg
        FROM follow
    ) b 
    ON lead.id = b.lead_id
    AND a.date = b.date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LEFT JOIN to find all rows in `follows` where there exists no newer row with the same lead_id. After that, you can join with `leads` as usual to get the result;

```
SELECT l.id lead_id, l.name, f.msg, f.date
FROM follow f
LEFT JOIN follow f_newer
  ON f.date < f_newer.date AND f.lead_id = f_newer.lead_id
JOIN leads l
  ON f.lead_id = l.id
WHERE f_newer.lead_id IS NULL
```

[A simple SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b47d/4).

You can also do it with a subquery that finds the max date per lead_id and uses that to find the correct rows;

```
SELECT l.id lead_id, l.name, f.msg, f.date
FROM follow f
JOIN leads l
  ON f.lead_id = l.id
WHERE (lead_id, date) IN (SELECT lead_id, MAX(date) FROM follow GROUP BY lead_id)
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b47d/14).